# viewForHeaderInSection - Customize only title label but not header section frame

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a unique situation.

I want to display custom header text for table header section which I am able to do but instead of custom header section solid color i want default header section frame gradient. (Please see attached image)

[image]

Here's what I am doing in `viewForHeaderInSection` method:

```
- (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *customSectionHeaderView;
    UILabel *titleLabel;

    customSectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 24)];
    titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 24)];
    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    [titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    titleLabel.text =  self.sortedPaths[section];

    [customSectionHeaderView addSubview:titleLabel];

    return customSectionHeaderView;
}
```

By removing

```
customSectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 24)];
```

I am able to get the result but then i can not add subview to it and return a view.

How can I achieve that gradient effect?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` instead? This gets you exactly what you're talking about: the default header with your text substituted.

Or you could just draw your own gradient, of course. iOS has excellent gradient-drawing methods.

Comment: I need title text indentation and that was the reason i used viewForHeaderInSection method. I can probably try drawing gradient but My goal is to get default gradient effect..

Comment: I could not find any useful answers online to draw the custom view with default gradient in viewForHeaderInSection method. I'd appreciate if you can guide me to the right resource. thanks!

Comment: You don't need to draw your own gradient. See the first part of the answer again: `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` is for when you want to customize the appearance of the view; if all you need is to change the text, implement [`tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:) instead.

Comment: And if you do want to draw your own gradient, you can draw any gradient you like.